# What functionality does /\ have? (one backslash and one forward slash)

Tags: java, escaping, backslash

I'm doing some code excercises before an exam in Java and I've stumbled upon a problem.

This is the output I want to get:

```
/\Oj, så många
/\leende och lyckliga
/\programmerare!
```

And the given code is:

```
public class Selektion_3_18 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Oj, så många leende och lyckliga programmerare!");
    }
}
```

I've tried googling the combination of back and forward slashes without getting a result.

My question is therefore; What is the functionality of /\? Or how am I supposed to use escape sequences to get the output they're asking for?

Comment: is this what you asking.. System.out.println("/\\test")... o/p /\test

Comment: What were your steps towards achieving the desired result so far?

Comment: It looks like it's just an output decoration. For forward slash you don't need any escape. As for your task, it's not clear what's programmatic about it. It just needs to format this specific string in this specific manner?

Comment: Usually, the function of the back slash is to let the programming language know it should represent the character as the character it was intended as.

If the function you are using the characters in  uses certain characters as commands then to tell it to ignore those commands you prepend them with a backslash.

So \/ is to note it's a forward slash for sure.
And \\ is to say "Don't use the back slash to escape the character after it, use is as an actual backslash.

Another example:

var str = "I am \"doublequoted\". See?";


Wow, I just confused myself too!

Comment: @AdamWhateverson A forward slash does not need an escape. So there is no need to precede it with a backslash, and the OP indicates that he wants both the forward slash and the backslash to appear in the output. So I see no reason to assume this is just an escape sequence.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yup, not writing any code here! I think they just want me to know about escape sequence... But I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use it here. The exercise before this one was the classic one with how to print quotes within quotes.

Comment: Well, in this case you'll need to think of how to put backslashes and newlines within quotes.

Comment: @RealSkeptic There are situations when even a forward slash needs to be escaped. I was being generic, not specific to Java. Sorry.

Comment: Agree with realskeptic, forward-slash doesn't need escape as back-slash does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could achieve something like:

```
System.out.println("/\\ Oj, så många\n/\\ leende och lyckliga\n/\\ programmerare!");
```

Forward-slash doesn't need escape as literal back-slash does,the back-slash is used to escape special characters, such as the one used in the above string \n. If you want to use a literal back-slash, a double back-slash must be used.